# Seeking polygonal river data complete with river bed width

Tags: data-request, geospatial, hydrology

I am trying to find data of rivers that are not made of simple lines. I need polygon data so that the river bed is visible.

Is there any global or regional data source?

Comment: not sure if this data fits exactly your needs. michigans rivers: http://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/076298de35ba420a8330df08492f018b_12/data if they work, i'll add them as an answer. if they don't, lmk what exactly is missing so i can conform my search.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, the rivers are real shapes not just lines. Are there more datasets like this for the whole world?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this is not polygon format, [MERIT Hydro: Global Hydrography Datasets](http://hydro.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Eyamadai/MERIT_Hydro/) does provide a raster of river width and this is a global dataset. You can convert this into a polygon format.